# How to expose kubeconfig file after create an EKS cluster by aws_eks_cluster with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

[eks module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) can generate an [output kubeconfig](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest#output_kubeconfig)

[aws_eks_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster) resource doesn't has this feature.

Why don't add this feature?

Comment: Ask at [github issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terraform eks module exposes that file by default, you can take a look at their files or even use their module. It's relatively easy to setup and works great. Links : [eks module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest), I am not 100% if [this](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/kubectl.tf) is the section for it but you can take the look at their whole repo.

Comment: Yes, I'm using resource but not module, just want to know why resource doesn't provide this feature.

Comment: Well I can't answer your question since I don't know. The terraform developers decided not to include it I guess, either way you put it, it was their decision.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is deprecated on v18 of the aws module, from [docs](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/docs/UPGRADE-18.0.md):

> Support for managing kubeconfig and its associated local_file
> resources have been removed; users are able to use the awscli provided
> aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name> to update their local
> kubeconfig as necessary